# Input array inside json by ajax not working properly in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm using Semantic UI and Laravel 6

I got this html code:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="realTime">Tiempo real</label>
    <input type="text" id="realTime" name="schedules[{{ $service->id_service }}][realTime]" required/>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="delayTime">Tiempo de demora</label>
    <input type="text" id="delayTime" name="schedules[{{ $service->id_service }}][delayTime]" required/>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="deathTime">Tiempo muerto</label>
    <input type="text" id="deathTime" name="schedules[{{ $service->id_service }}][deathTime]" required/>
</div>
```

And I'm sending this info by ajax using this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    data: {
        "formData": $(formClass).form('get values')
    },
    success: function (response) {
        // skipped code
    }
});
```

But when I dump the request data in controller using:

```
dd($request->input('formData'));
```

I got this result:

```
array:1 [
  "formData" => array:1 [
    "schedules[1" => array:3 [
      "realTime" => "12:00:00"
      "delayTime" => "13:00:00"
      "deathTime" => "14:00:00"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Instead of:

```
array:1 [
  "formData" => array:1 [
    "schedules" => array:1 [
      1 => array:3 [
         "realTime" => "12:00:00"
         "delayTime" => "13:00:00"
         "deathTime" => "14:00:00"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I checked out the content sent shown in Headers tab (using Chrome) and I found this:

```
formData[schedules[1][realTime]]: 12:00:00
formData[schedules[1][delayTime]]: 13:00:00
formData[schedules[1][deathTime]]: 14:00:00
```

I also realized that if I put the name as `"schedules][{{ $service->id_service }}][realTime]"` (putting an extra closing bracket after "schedules"), the dump shows the array correctly.

Any solution?